# Choosing a appropriate demonstrative pronoun

Tags: grammar

I wonder whether 'Those' should be replaced by 'It' because 'Those' refers to acupuncture. I think if 'Those' refers to 'some studies', "Those have actually been shown to be" should be rewritten as "Those have actually shown it is". This comes up in a YouTube video https://youtu.be/JrzumXTQQ2M?t=510

> and there are some studies that have compared acupuncture with some of
> the standard oral medications that we have like topiramate and the
> beta blockers. Those have actually been shown to be helpful for
> migraine prevention and can cause less side effects than oral
> medications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. It makes no sense. There are other ways to rewrite it so that it makes sense, but no need to go into that.